# Is the String method isEmpty really not available in Android API Levels < 10?

Tags: java, android, string, netbeans

I am using NetBeans and `nbandroid` to build my Android app. Previously I was targeting API level 10 (2.3.3) but I realized that in doing so I would be excluding too many people from my app and (I thought) my app did not use any features that exceeded API level 7. However, after changing my API level in project properties in NetBeans, my project will not compile and fails on compiling a `myString.isEmpty()` conditional. I know this is easily fixed/replaced, but is `String.isEmpty` really not available until API level 10? If not, how do I fix my `nbandroid` project? I have noticed that even after I choose API level in project properties, under libraries it always says Android 2.3.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably still says your using the 2.3.3 library as you have `targetSdk` set to 2.3.3.

---

With a Min SDK of over **2.2 (8)** you will lose **27.1%** of the audience

With a Min SDK of over **2.1 (7)** you will lose **6.2%**

With a Min SDK of over **1.6 (6)** you will lose **0.7%**

so it's up to you if you don't want to target over **2.3 (9)**.

(*I would personally recommend having your minSdk as 2.2 (8) and targeting 3.0 (11)*)

---

As for String.isEmpty()

```
 if("".equals(String)){
   // is Empty
 }
```

or

```
 if(!"".equals(String) && String != null){
   // is Not Empty
 }
```

For a complete isEmpty implementation you need to remember your string may be null or full of spaces (which is technically empty):

```
 if(String != null && "".equals(String.trim())){
   // is Empty
 }
```

Checking for null allows you to call the `trim()` method without a NullPointerException

Ref:

[Stats reference](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html)

Comment: Thanks for all the info. I was surprised to learn that the `isEmpty()` method was not available until 9.

Comment: I've just realised you might want to use trim() I'll edit my answer

Comment: There is also `TextUtils.isEmpty()`

Answer (score 4):

More effective way to check if the string is empty ( in absence of `isEmpty` method ) is to check that its length is 0 vs. using `equals`, as in:

```
if ( myString.length() == 0 )
{
  // is emtpy
}
```

Actually, that's what the `isEmpty` is doing behind the scene.

Comment: If the `String` is `null` will it throw a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: @jshin47. Yes, but `null` is not a `String`.  You would have the same problem with `isEmpty`

Answer (score 3):

isEmpty was added with API 9. ([Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty%28%29))

You can still convert your application to API 7 if you wish, you'd need to use `String.length() != 0` rather than `isEmpty();`

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty%28%29)'s the documentation. It is available from API 9 and on. As you said, it's pretty easily replaced.

Answer (score 1):

It's there, [since level nine](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty%28%29).